# mysql innodb primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, uuid, database-performance

Currently we have tables that has type 4 UUID(random) as primary key.
Our application layer does a batch insert into DB.
But still since the primary key is random, this will result in multiple disk spins.
There are four tables.

```
CREATE TABLE process (
     process_id binary(16) not null, // uuid
     created_time bigint not null,
     owner varchar(150) not null,
     primary key (process_id),
     index idx_c_t (created_time),
     index idx_o (owner)
)
Records inserted = 2000/min

CREATE TABLE process_job (
     job_id binary(16) not null, //uuid
     process_id binary(16) not null,  //uuid
     info varchar(200),
     text varchar(500),
     primary key(job_id),
     index idx_p_id (process_id)
)
Records inserted = 10000/min

CREATE TABLE ob_status (
     job_id binary(16) not null, //uuid
     status ('STARTED', 'SUCCESS', 'ERROR') not null,
     job_code varchar(100) not null,
     info varchar(200),
     text varchar(500),
     primary key(job_id, status, job_code)
)
Records inserted = 20000/min


CREATE TABLE process_job_custom (
     job_id binary(16) not null, //uuid
     key varchar(100) not null,
     value varchar(500),
     primary key(process_id, key)
)
Records inserted = 10000/min
```

All our tables use DYNAMIC format.

Further we delete 15 days old data periodically.
We run this deletes in batches by considering around 1000 records.
But when ever the deletes run, the whole db performance is bad. Disk usage is very high.(we suspect this is due to the randomness of the primary key)

So we are planning to alter our primary key as (time based key, uuid) and add index on (uuid) columns.

The records may arrive in random order(not exactly in the time based key order).
But the records for a time based key arrives mostly within 5 minute spread.
Also our deletes are based on the time based key.

Will this affect the performance of inserts?

Also our primary use cases involve time based queries.
So will the select performance also increase?

Further we are planning on partitioning by time based key.

Will this help us in better performance overall?

We suspect the major issue was the randomness of the primary key.

Will add the time based key(something like created time of the process) as the first part of the primary key in the all the tables and indexing based on the uuid columns help us?

Comment: You should always have a sequentially increased integer as your primary key when using InnoDB. It's due to how InnoDB stores data so I won't get into that (it's to do with rebalancing the index tree). Have your GUIDs as secondary keys, along with other keys and you should experience performance gains. Naturally, set your innodb_buffer_pool to a decent size.

Comment: Our innodb_buufer_pool is 24G. Does having created_time + uuid as primary key improve the performance? Or it has to be strictly increasing integer for any performance benifit?

Comment: The reason why you want an integer (only) as PK is because of the way InnoDB saves the data and constructs the tree with the indexes. The data on the disk is saved in the order of the index in the tree. If, say, you inserted numbers 1 - 20, but then you want to insert number 15 - InnoDB has to rebuild the tree from the selected index (I can't explain it better than that). That means the tree has to be rebalanced, and it's balanced using the PK value. So, if the PK value is always larger than the previous one - the rebalancing isn't needed. That reduces I/O.

Comment: That means, if you have an auto_increment as PK, and then set your secondary indexes (guid, time) - that'll save the calculations and I/O. Judging by the initial post, you're dealing with mechanical drives which reach about 400ish IOPS, opposed to an SSD that reaches 85k+. You should look into modifying the PK AND upgrading the disk subsystem if insertion / deletion performance is of importance. Additionally, [the following presentation](http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/percona-live/london-2011/PLUK2011-b-tree-indexes-and-innodb.pdf) might be of help in deciding about indexes.